# Launch new instance of program, then terminate the old one

Tags: shell

I'm looking to automate recording of an https audio stream using VLC.  The stream has a tendency to drop, so I need to create a new capture every hour on the hour, but for the sake of smooth editing I'd like each instance to record 65 minutes.

I'm not sure how to script this so that the old one terminates 5 minutes after the new one has launched.

The command I'm using for the capture is:

```
vlc https://server.com/live --sout="#duplicate{dst=std{access=file,mux=mp3,dst='/home/ubuntu/test1.mp3'},dst=nodisplay}"
```

(Additionally, I'd like to replace "test1" with current date time information, but that's another thread.)

Answer (score 0):

Better exit [vlc](/questions/tagged/vlc) cleanly than killing the process:

`--stop-time=3900` (65 * 60)

> Stop time
>   The stream will stop at this position (in seconds).

https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/

The rest could be done with a shell loop:

```
while : ; do 
    vlc --stop-time=3900 --play-and-exit https://server.com/live --sout="#duplicate{dst=std{access=file,mux=mp3,dst='/home/ubuntu/test1.mp3'},dst=nodisplay}" &
    sleep 3600
done
```

The `while do : ; vlc &; sleep 3600 done` launches an instance in the background, than waits 3600 seconds, than launced the next instance forever (until you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>).

Another option, could be to use a crontab entry, that just starts a new instance every full hour:
`crontab -e`

```
0 * * * * vlc --stop-time=3900 --play-and-exit https://server.com/live --sout="#duplicate{dst=std{access=file,mux=mp3,dst='/home/ubuntu/test1.mp3'},dst=nodisplay}" 1>>~/.vlc.dump.log 2>&1
```

---

**Edit:** As @DaveZachritz poited out it also needs `--play-and-exit`

Comment: I tried that and it only ran once.  Putting in a much shorter stop-time and just executing the command itself, it only stops the stream, it doesn't actually exit VLC.